# Are there any good books on emptiness outside of Buddhism?

Tags: reference-request

I am not a Buddhist (yet) but marinating in Buddhist philosophy and secularized Buddhist practices. I have problemes with their cosmology and some of the meatphysics.

I started pracitcing after hearing an introductory lecture on Nagarjuna's Mūlamadhyamakakārikā, perhaps the earliest known systematic presentation of emptiness.

Does anyone have a good tip for books thst gives a comprehensive presentation of the philosophy of emptiness outside of Buddhism?

Comment: Do you ask for a book about the Buddhist notion of emptiness written by a non-Buddhist? Or do you ask for a book about a non-Buddhist philosophy of emptiness?

Comment: Non Buddhist philosophy of Emptiness. Sorry, English is not my native language

Comment: See Gay Watson, [A Philosophy of Emptiness](http://press.uchicago.edu/ucp/books/book/distributed/P/bo18015403.html) (2014).

Comment: Possibly : Steven W. Laycock, [Nothingness and Emptiness: A Buddhist Engagement with the Ontology of Jean-Paul Sartre](https://books.google.it/books?id=vJix57OfR5gC&printsec=frontcover) (2001), for connections with [Sartre](http://plato.stanford.edu/entries/sartre/) book : [L'Être et le néant (Being and Nothingness)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Being_and_Nothingness) (1943).

Comment: @MauroALLEGRANZA, thanks for tips, I'll try them out, the Watson book seem right up my alley

Comment: Books by Mark Siderits or Garfield are good; Garfield in particular has written on Nagarjuna.

Comment: @MoziburUllah yes thanks. I'm aware of that and know their work well (I wrote my ba in philosophy on Nagarjuna, using both Siderits and Garfield). However, the question here was not about Nagarjuna or Buddhism. As for Nagarjuna, check out Richard Jones' work, he is really interesting and quite at odds with the new postmodern Garfield/Priest interpretation of Nagarjuna.

Answer (score 2):

**"Sitting in Oblivion" by Livia Kohn** addresses the idea of *zuowang*, a Daoist practice which involves a notion of oblivion or emptiness that is comparable to the Buddhist idea. Within the text, there are comparisons made to Buddhism, but the topic of the text is mainly Daoist. Here is a quote from the text, describing *zuowang*:

> *"“I let my limbs and physical structure fall away, do away with perception and intellect, separate myself from body-form and let go of all knowledge, thus joining Great Pervasion. This is what I mean by ‘sitting in oblivion’.” So runs the classic passage in Zhuangzi 6. Also explained with the phrase “making one’s body like dried wood and one’s mind like dead ashes” (chs. 2, 22), it describes a state where all visceral awareness of emotions and desires is lost and all sense perception is cut off."* -- pg. 17, "Sitting in Oblivion" by Livia Kohn